# How to run javascript on a webpage using cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I'm writing a cypress test and following javascript works in the chrome console

```
$.event.trigger({
type: "Scan",
message: "scanned",
time: new Date()
});
```

Is there a way I can run the command above in cypress when I get to the specific page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this within a `.then()` block. Since cy commands run asynchronously and get queued up with all the other cy commands, `.then()` will delay the execution of the JavaScript within until the cy command actually does its thing.

So like this...

```
cy.visit('/my-special-page').then(() => {
   // Do your JavaScript here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Cypress.$.event.trigger({
> type: "Scan",
> message: "scanned",
> time: new Date()
> });

Comment: Tried this previously but for some reason nothing happens